# Howto refresh lightgallery when dynamicEl has changed

Tags: lightgallery

I have different albums, the contents of which I want to show in lightgallery.

My initial call goes like :

```
$('.dlCms_c_Carousel').lightGallery({
                                    dynamic   : true ,
                                    dynamicEl : dlThis.LGDynEl ,
                                    thumbnail : true ,
                                    mode      : 'lg-fade' ,
                                    });
```

This works perfect, but then, when opening another album, I want the one or the other way to refresh such that the new content of dynamicEl is shown.

Is there a way to do it ?

I was trying a

```
$('.dlCms_c_Carousel').data("lightGallery").destroy(true)
```

before, but that messed up. I.e. there seemed to be some functionality, but it looked like the lightbox lost some styling and wasn't opaque any more.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Waypoint.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) for infinite scrolling with lightgallery.

The solution that I found for dynamic refresh was:

```js
var gallery = $(".infinite-container").lightGallery({
  selector: '.item'
});

var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
  element: document.querySelector('.infinite-container'),
  onAfterPageLoad: () => {
    gallery.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
    gallery = $(".infinite-container").lightGallery({
      selector: '.item'
    });
  }
});
```

From my experience, the object returned from the lightgallery initialization has to be used on the destroy.

Hope it helps.